# All Windows 10 Apps Icons Disappeared

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons, windows-10-apps

I have windows 10 installed on an HP laptop. My taskbar appears to be working as usual, until I try to open any of the windows apps (the ones that came preinstalled on the computer and I can't uninstall). This includes photos, groove music, camera, alarms & clocks, calculator, settings etc.
So, if I open any of these apps, all I see is a blank square that I can hover over and then see which app it is.
On the start menu I see all the apps and their icons as usual. 
 On other users this problem doesn't exist. I'm really lost, I've almost given up and just opened a new user.

I've tried almost every solution that I found online and nothing helped.
I've looked endlessly online for solutions and tried them all. Problem is, I can't find the exact problem listed anywhere. 
Updating the apps doesn't work. Also reinstalling them does nothing. It's a bigger problem than that. It's ALL the windows apps. But not the other apps that I installed.
 Neither does deleting the icon cache.

Originally, I played with the cmd and tried to delete a few of the system apps, such as people and my phone. I think the icons disappeared somewhere around then. Before that everything worked great.
Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: What exact commands did you execute when you tried to get rid of the system apps?

Comment: I **think** it was: Get-AppxPackage appname | Remove-AppxPackage